# Entity Framework and composite primary key with STORE, ID and DATE

Tags: c#, entity

I'm trying to add an object to a List, and the exception is occurring below.
My table is as follows:

```
PK INT STORE
PK id INT (IDENTITY)
PK DATE DATE
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (200)
```

The code:

```
using (SIACEntities bd = new SIACEntities())
{
  bd.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;


  bd.ITEMs.Add(item);
  bd.SaveChanges();   ->>>> Exception
}
```

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: How do you initialize your item? Try to catch DbUpdateException and see the exact internal error. It should be a problem with primary key not initialise correctly, or bad foreign key, or whatever could happen bad to an update.

Comment: Cyril Gandon you are alright. I solved the problem converting the DateTime to Date. Like this: 'item.DATE = item.DATA.Date;' Thank you very much!!!